# ASP.NET Core : UseRequestLocalization why do we need to specify a list of supported cultures?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, culture

My goal is to use the browser language as the culture used in my controllers / views.

I found out about `app.UseRequestLocalization()` but just by itself it won't work, it only accept the current server culture. It needs options to add a list of supported culture for it to work:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var supportedCultures = new string[] { "en-US", "en-CA", "fr-CA", "fr-FR" };
    options.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
        .SetDefaultCulture("en-US");
});
```

This way, my browser sends `fr-FR` in the `accept-language` header, and the request comes to my ASP.NET Core controller correctly under the `Thread.CurrentCulture` property.

My question is, how to accept all cultures? Why do we need to supply a list of "supported" ones?

I understand localization dictionaries are only translated in your project for a certain list of cultures. But when it doesn't it fall back to English anyway. Having all cultures accepted would still help for cases like `DateTime.ToString()` and number formatting and such.

Is there an easy way to have all cultures automatically accepted (like in previous ASP.NET versions before Core)?

Answer (score 2):

This is the best I could do, using `CultureInfo.GetCultures()` to list them all.

If anyone have a justification on why I shouldn't do this (performance hit?), or a better alternative, feel free to post another answer!

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(options =>
{
    var cinfo = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    var supportedCultures = cinfo.Select(t => t.Name).Distinct().ToArray();
    options.AddSupportedCultures(supportedCultures)
        .AddSupportedUICultures(supportedCultures)
        .SetDefaultCulture("en-US");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> My question is, how to accept all cultures? Why do we need to supply a list of "supported" ones?

I think there should be no such method or libraries as you mentioned. Generally, in .net core, Name-Value is added for the language used by the customer population.

According to the official documentation, we can see that in the .resx file, if you want to translate accurately, every word needs to be matched. If you want to support all languages, it will take a lot of work. It is estimated that if you want to translate accurately, you need to be able to speak various languages.

By analogy, does Google Translate sometimes have inaccurate translations? It may be caused by unfamiliarity with the usage of some special languages.

Comment: As I explained in the question, this is not about translating the application resources strings in every language. This is about taking advantage of the regional output of framework types for dates, times, numbers, units, etc. It is standard in a .NET application (console/winforms/etc) for them to be printed this way via ToString().

Comment: More justification: Outside of the framework base types that gains advantage of it, I have a class using RegionInfo.IsMetric() to determine if the speed unit is km/h or mph in this culture. "en-US" and "en-CA" returns different result. Adding just "en" in the list of supported prevent this from being available, but adding both works.