# ASP.NET Core - app.UseRequestLocalization() middleware more than 2 parameters problem

Tags: localization, internationalization, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-7.0

I'm trying to create multi language API. I created simple ASP.NET Core 7 Web API project.

My `Program.cs` looks like this:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();    
var app = builder.Build();

app.UseRequestLocalization("it", "el");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}    

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

As you can see I did not install any packages, just add one line of code:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("it", "el");
```

I have following Resources files:

[image]

Inside the `Resources` files I defined single variable `txt` with different values for different languages:

`txt: one/ένας/ერთი/один/una`

`TempResource.resx` has a public modifier:

[image]

Other `TempResource` files ('it', 'ka', 'ru') do not have any modifier:

[image]

and have controller method where I'm printing Resources `txt` variable:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TempController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("temp")]
    public string GetTemp()
    {
        return TempResource.txt;
    }
}
```

So everything works fine!

If first parameter is 'el':

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("el", "it");
```

link:

```
localhost/api/Temp/temp
```

The result is: `ένας`

If first parameter is 'it':

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("it", "el");
```

Link:

```
localhost/api/Temp/temp
```

Result is: `una`

Problem begins when `UseRequestLocalization()` takes more than 2 parameters:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization("it", "el", "ka", "ru");
```

Doesn't matter witch language is on the first place, sometimes result matches first parameter and sometimes - not; I can't understand the logic.

Desired behavior: first parameter should be used in any cases. Please help to fix the problem.

PS: in all cases these lines works correctly:

`localhost/api/Temp/temp/?culture=el&ui-culture=el` -> `ένας`

`localhost/api/Temp/temp/?culture=ru&ui-culture=ru` -> `один`

`localhost/api/Temp/temp/?culture=ka&ui-culture=ka` -> `ერთი`

`localhost/api/Temp/temp/?culture=it&ui-culture=it` -> `una`

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation, No matter what the first parameter is , It always return the value in `TempResource.resx` instead of `TempResource.xxx.resx`

Comment: @XinranShen in my case somethimes it returns the value in TempResource.resx and sometimes - TempResource.xxx.resx

Comment: You can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69095210/asp-net-core-userequestlocalization-why-do-we-need-to-specify-a-list-of-suppor) to set the default language.

Comment: @XinranShen it does not work

Comment: It's weird, I never met this situation before. Even can't reproduce it in my demo.